# jQuery append link into menu in a specific spot

Tags: jquery

Here is the html for a vertical menu , i do not have access to alter the HTML , but i can use jQuery to append the menu. I want to add a link to the menu , but when i do , it gets added to every submenu , so how can i specify which part of the menu to add it to?

I had to set up a jsfiddle to illustrate as i posted the code for the menu here and it just showed the links and not html for some reason

Here is the script i'm running to try to get this done

```
$("#vsubmenuitems ul").append('<li><a href="#">MY NEW LINK</a></li>');
});
```

JS FIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/5Z7ec/

Comment: So where do you want to append it?

Comment: at the bottom of the first column of links , under Link 4

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5Z7ec/2/ ?

Comment: perfect ! , so i see how to do first and last , how do i apply to the middle column if needed in future ?  Do i use the css nth-of-type ?

Comment: ul:nth-child(2n) and ul:nth-child(2) or ul:nth-of-type(2) didn't work

Comment: You can use `:nth(n)` selector: http://jsfiddle.net/5Z7ec/11/

Comment: thx dfsq , learned something new today

Comment: How would i add links to a new submenu title i added ?  http://jsfiddle.net/5Z7ec/76/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are so many ways to do so:

First of all I would recommend you to visit: **[jQuery Basics: Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**

**1. You can use `$("#someID")` to append something specific, when you assign IDs.**

**2. You can use `$("#vsubmenuitems ul:nth-child(n))` Which represent the number of child you want to append .. (1,2,3).**

**3. You can use `$("#vsubmenuitems ul:first)` | `$("#vsubmenuitems ul:last)` which is obvious.**

But above all this, please refer to jQuery basics: Selectors, to understand better, and to improve your code.

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

Use `$("#vsubmenuitems ul:eq(0)")` to select the first list (1 for 2nd, etc.)

[JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Z7ec/3/)